# Reversing encryption in delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe2

It was not me who wrote this code, it was the previous programmer. However, I noticed he didn't provide a decryption algorithm, rendering the encryption useless.

How can I decrypt this?

```
function Encrypt(jstr: String): String;
var
  I: Integer;
  A: Real;
begin
  if Length(jstr) = 0 Then begin
    Result := '';
    Exit;
  end;
  A := 0;
    for I := 0 To Length(jstr) do
      A := A + (Ord(jstr[I]) * Pos(jstr[I],jstr)) / 33;
  Result := FormatFloat('0000000000.0000000000',A);
  if Pos(',',Result) > 0 then begin
    Insert('.',Result,Pos(',',Result));
    Delete(Result,Pos(',',Result),1);
  end;
end;
```

Thanks!

Comment: As a hint: You don't need to put every line into <code></code>. Just add 4 spaces in front of each line and you'll have the highlighted code formatting

Comment: Good luck it is not encryption without key.

Comment: @ralu that's not the issue, the entire code for the so called encryption is in the Q, there is no key

Comment: It appears that the comma replacement is to force the decimal character to a period. If you're still using this function, I would make use of the DecimalSeparator global variable in the replacement portion instead of coding in the comma.

Comment: "Floating point encryption techniques" might even create different output on different CPUs, thanks possible differences in rounding errors in their floating point engines.  This is a crappy way to write a hash. I wouldn't reuse this code, ever.

Comment: It won't even work in modern Delphis, since it uses [0] index of a string, which is only defined in ShortStrings in newer Delphi versions, unless {$H-} is used.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That function cannot be reversed. Since it takes input of arbitrary length and returns output of finite length, simple information theory tells you the futility of attempting to write a general inverse. Even for shorter input strings it seems to me that different input strings can result in the same *encrypted* string.

Even as a hash this function seems very brittle to me due to the bizarre use of floating point code. If I were you I would replace this function with something more fit for purpose.

Finally, I recommend that you undertake a review of all code produced by this developer. The low quality of this code and algorithm suggests to me that everything that this developer touched is liable to have defects.

Comment: Love your final paragraph there David :-)

Comment: Indeed, your last paragraph gave me inspiration to do some rewriting to a more clean and functional code. Thanks man.

Comment: Floating point encryption is deserving of a spot on the Daily-WTF site.

Comment: I bet most of us at some point thought we were smart enough to create our own encryption scheme! We all ought be warned early in our careers not to dabble in crypto on our own :-)

Answer (score 20):

It looks like a one way hash and hence is not reversible. For example, is the string is very big the result is still a string representation of a float.